$H^\infty$ functions with certain $H^2$ factors
While discussing the factorization theorems and shift-cyclicity in Hardy spaces, a friend and I came across a problem that seems to be answerable but we could not get anywhere. The problem is as follows:
Find all $f \in H^2(\mathbb{D})$ such that $(z-1)f \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$. What happens if we change $z-1$ with any outer function?
Here, $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ represents the space of bounded analytic functions on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, and $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ represents the space of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ whose power-series coefficients are square-summable.
Of course, if $f \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ then $(z-1)f \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ is trivial. So we are looking for some kind of examples for which $f \not\in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ but $(z-1)f \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$. It is also clear from the inner-outer factorization that classifying all such $f \in H^2(\mathbb{D})$ can be reduced to finding all such $f \in H^2(\mathbb{D})$ that are outer but we could not see how to proceed with this either.
Any help is appreciated!

I am not exactly sure how the answer should look like? If we write $f = IO$, where $O = \exp(g)$, then what you need is for $u = Re, g$ (the harmonic function on which everything here depends) that its boundary values satisfy $ \exp (u)\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and $u \le C-\log |1-z|$ for some $C$, and this is an if and only if condition.

If a concrete example is what you are after, then $f(z)=\log (1-z)$ works. This is in $H^2$ because the Taylor coefficients $a_n=1/n$ are square summable.

@ChristianRemling Oh, of course! Thanks :) We need to find $H^2$ functions with a "weaker" singularity at $z=1$, and the logarithm does the trick. So something like $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^p}$ where $0 < p < 1/2$ also works, right?

@AlekseiKulikov I see. I suspect this is the best we could do in terms of complete classification then. Thanks :)
